# Bounding box for app engine?

Tags: spatial-database, extents

I'm using python 2.7 and app engine. To do bounding box we used [geomodel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/) but it executes more then 5 seconds in table with 350 records. It's to slow. 
Can you please suggest better solution ? 
Is there online solution to store data and then execute bounding box search ?

Comment: Have you considered using pyrtree? It's pure Python, so I'm guessing it might be allowed on GAE.

Comment: Oleg, I'd be tempted to calculate it manually; 350 records isn't an awful lot of records to 'sort' in code.

Comment: You, are right. But we have it now. In the future it will be more than 100 thousands. So the solution should work for such amount.

Comment: Does your data need to remain in the format of geomodel? If not, what format does it live in?